# How can I crate a table if not exist in the db using mysql dump in window os ?Give me mysqldump cmd

Tags: mysql, mysqldumpslow

mysqldump -h -u  -p --set-gtid-purged=OFF sourcs_db tablename --where="syncdate between '2024-02-09 00:00:00' and '2024-02-09 23:59:59'" >  C:\Mayur\Dump\dump.sql

Comment: ??post errors if you have them , and I don't understand the title or how it relates to the published code.